# Why xPath assumes namespace

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-namespaces

xPath in SelectNodes method below does not return any node, even if there are such nodes in xCurrent document.

```
XmlDocument xCurrent = new XmlDocument();
xCurrent.Load(File);
foreach (XmlNode Node in xCurrent.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Product"))
{
    ...
}
```

My assumption that it should is based on this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

**//author** All <author> elements in the document.

However I've found that following xPath returns what is required

```
xCurrent.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()=\"Product\"]"))
```

It seems for me that xPath assumes that "//Product" means "//elibri:Product", because "//" xPath returns only "elibri:Dialect" node. What is the reason behind that assumption? List of child nodes of `DocumentElement` is below.

[image: List of child nodes from VS debugger]

Comment: Please could you show us a short example of the document? My guess is that it's got a default namespace (`xmlns="..."`) at some point, but we're guessing until we see the doc. As an aside, LINQ to XML (XDocument etc) makes it really easy to work with namespaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean that part do that:
`<ONIXMessage release="3.0" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference" xmlns:elibri="http://elibri.com.pl/ns/extensions">`

?

Comment: Yes. Any child elements of that element will default to a namespace of `"http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference"`. (That's not a .NET thing - it's just regular XML.)